# Access VBA adjusting axis min/max

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a form with a graph where users can enter values to adjust the min/max values for both axes. What I am doing works for the primary, but not the secondary axis.

```
Private Sub UpdateAxis_Click()
    Me.Scattergram.PrimaryValuesAxisRange = acAxisRangeFixed
    Me.Scattergram.SecondaryValuesAxisRange = acAxisRangeFixed
    Me.Scattergram.PrimaryValuesAxisMinimum = Me.MinValue
    Me.Scattergram.PrimaryValuesAxisMaximum = Me.MaxValue
    Me.Scattergram.SecondaryValuesAxisMinimum = Me.FirstDate
    Me.Scattergram.SecondaryValuesAxisMaximum = Me.LastDate
    Me.Scattergram.Requery

End Sub
```

This code works to change the primary axis but does not affect the secondary axis (I have set all the min/max to static values as a test and I get the same result).

```
Private Sub UpdateAxis_Click()
    Me.Scattergram.PrimaryValuesAxisRange = acAxisRangeFixed
    Me.Scattergram.SecondaryValuesAxisRange = acAxisRangeFixed
    Me.Scattergram.PrimaryValuesAxisMinimum = 0
    Me.Scattergram.PrimaryValuesAxisMaximum = 40
    Me.Scattergram.SecondaryValuesAxisMinimum = 42033
    Me.Scattergram.SecondaryValuesAxisMaximum = 44127
    Me.Scattergram.Requery

End Sub
```

The odd thing is that this was working at one point and I'm 99% sure it stopped working after I did a "Compact & Repair" on the database.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is this an Access Modern Chart? The syntax is different from what I have used for classic MS Graph.

Comment: Yes - this is a Modern Chart.